# Converting 2 node cassandra Cluster to 1 node cluster

Tags: datastax, cassandra-2.1

I have 2 node cassandra cluster. I intend to split them to two single node clusters.

1. Shut Down Both Cassandra Instances
2. Edit cassandra.yaml in both nodes, Changed seeds to point to self, and set endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
3. Start Cassandra on both nodes

**Nodetool Status** command on both the nodes shows 2 nodes, while I expect only one node.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that each node still thinks its part of a 2 node cluster. It will remain like this until you tell it otherwise. Assuming you need to keep the data on each node then you need to run `nodetool removenode <id>` on each node for the other node thats showing up as `DN` in the output of `nodetool status`. If you didn't need the data on both nodes you can also use `nodetool decommission`

For some background information on removing nodes please [see this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRemoveNode.html).

Note that if you intend to re-join these two nodes together then I would strongly advise you wipe and bootstrap one of the nodes into the the existing cluster since you can end up with a schema disagreement trying to join two clusters.